# Check if a file has been written to in Android

Tags: android, file, file-io

I have a question about Android programming. Basically, I am unsure of where to check where my file is, and if I wrote to it correctly. I want to locate where the file is, and I also want to know whether or not I wrote to it correctly. Below is the code I have come up with:

```
String lsNow = "testing";
try {
    fos = openFileOutput("output.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(lsNow.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
catch{
...
}
```

Where can I find output.txt? Might anyone know how to check this all out? if so, that would be great! I am using an emulator by the way. If I were to do this on a real Android, how would one approach this also? (Just for future reference)

Comment: You can locate your text file in `/data/data/<your package name>/files` folder. You can use emulator to grab it or a rooted device If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to grab it in the emulator if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: Apologies. Use the DDMS > File explorer.

Comment: @system32 : Don't advise people to use hard-coded paths such as `/data/data/<your package name>/files` - that goes against the way things are supposed to work. There is no guarantee that any given device manufacturer will follow that pattern which is precisely why the `openFileOutput(...)` and `openFileInput(...)` methods exist.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks friend. +1 For that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Test it in Two ways

1. Using File Explorer

   Go to DDMS perspective--> Open File Explorer-->location of the file
2. Pragrammatically by using `exits()` method

   File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        if(file.exists())

Comment: In you eclipse goto --->Window--->Preferences--->Android->File Explorer and in the file explorer check your file in the sd card

Comment: @Pragnani : Using `openFileOutput(...)` does not write to the SD card - it writes to internal storage.

Comment: Sorry for that....I have escape show view option now the order is In you eclipse goto --->Window--->Show View--->Android-->File Explorer

Comment: in File Explorer data/data/your_project_package_structure/files/output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Using `openFileOutput(...)` means the file will be written to internal storage on the Android device in an area which is secure from access by other apps.

If you want to make sure the file is written correctly then make sure your `catch` block handles any failures (if it is called then the file writing has failed).

To access the file once it has been written use `openFileInput(...)`.